# MASS Package in R: "lower" of fitdistr(x,"weibull",lower=T)

Tags: r

Is "lower" changing the densfunction to 
`y=shape/scale*(x/scale)^(shape-1) *e^((T^shape-x^shape)/(scale^shape))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it changes the range within which the function searches for optimal parameter values. The distribution remains (from `?dweibull`):

> f(x) = (a/b) (x/b)^(a-1) exp(- (x/b)^a)

As usual, one of the best ways to figure this stuff out is to experiment.  Simulate some data and fit:

```
set.seed(101)
library(MASS)
z <- rweibull(1000,shape=2,scale=5)
fitdistr(z,"weibull")             
##     shape        scale   
##   1.99894352   5.06797419 
##  (0.04950087) (0.08437483)
```

Now set a lower bound, but one that is *non-binding* - i.e. the estimated parameters are both above the lower bound:

```
fitdistr(z,"weibull",lower=c(1,4))
##     shape        scale   
##  1.99894311   5.06797394 
## (0.04950086) (0.08437484)
```

The answer is practically identical.

Now set a binding lower bound for one of the parameters:

```
fitdistr(z,"weibull",lower=c(2.5,4))
##      shape        scale   
##  2.50000000   5.32522699 
## (0.05815129) (0.07329413)
```

It seems as though you might be looking for a *truncated Weibull* distribution:

```
library("sos")
findFn("{truncated weibull}")
```